# Fall edge interrupt constantly triggering without any visible edge

Tags: arduino, interrupts, gpio-external-interrupt, sparkfun

I'm trying to implement a button-operated sleep mode toggle on a Sparkfun Artemis module. Button press one puts the Artemis to sleep, button press two wakes it up. I'm coding it in the Arduino IDE and I've been running into this one problem. Basically, as soon as I reach then line in setup that attaches the interrupt routine to the pin/button, the interrupt IMMEDIATELY triggers and sends it into sleep mode.

The interrupt is configured to trigger on a Falling Edge, and is pulled high both internally and externally by a 10k resistor, seen below:

[image: interrupt debounce circuit]

Below is also the relevant code for the interrupt, sleeping and waking up. According to the debug outputs on the serial monitor, as soon as the attachInterrupt() line runs, the interrupt triggers and the device goes to sleep.

```
void setup(void)
{
  int cnt = 0;
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // initialize the built-in LED pin to indicate when a central is connected
  pinMode(BATTERY_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SLEEP_INTERRUPT, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(SLEEP_INTERRUPT, HIGH);
  delay(50);
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.begin(115200);
#endif
  ledTimer = millis() ;
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("About to attach interrupt. button status: "); Serial.println(digitalRead(SLEEP_INTERRUPT));
#endif
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(SLEEP_INTERRUPT), sleepModeSwitch, FALLING);
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("Interrupt attached");
#endif
  deepSleepTimer = millis() ;
}

void sleepModeSwitch()
{
  if(sleep_mode_status == false)
  {
    goToSleep();
  }
  else
  {
    wakeUp();
  }
}

void goToSleep()
{
  sleep_mode_status = true;
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.println("Going to sleep");
  delay(50);  //Wait for serial to finish
  Serial.end(); //Power down UART(s)
#endif
  // turn off the led.
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  // Stop the BLE advertising.
  BLE.stopAdvertise() ;

  powerControlADC(false);
  
  for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
  {
    if(x != SLEEP_INTERRUPT)
    {
      am_hal_gpio_pinconfig(x, g_AM_HAL_GPIO_DISABLE);
    }
  }
  //Power down Flash, SRAM, cache
  am_hal_pwrctrl_memory_deepsleep_powerdown(AM_HAL_PWRCTRL_MEM_CACHE); //Turn off CACHE
  am_hal_pwrctrl_memory_deepsleep_powerdown(AM_HAL_PWRCTRL_MEM_FLASH_512K); //Turn off everything but lower 512k
  am_hal_pwrctrl_memory_deepsleep_powerdown(AM_HAL_PWRCTRL_MEM_SRAM_64K_DTCM); //Turn off everything but lower 64k
  //am_hal_pwrctrl_memory_deepsleep_powerdown(AM_HAL_PWRCTRL_MEM_ALL); //Turn off all memory (doesn't recover)
  
  // // Enable interrupts to the core.
  am_hal_interrupt_master_enable();
  
  // //Enable the timer interrupt in the NVIC.
  // NVIC_EnableIRQ(STIMER_CMPR6_IRQn);

  //Go to Deep Sleep.
  am_hal_sysctrl_sleep(AM_HAL_SYSCTRL_SLEEP_DEEP);
}

void wakeUp()
{
  am_hal_pwrctrl_memory_deepsleep_powerdown(AM_HAL_PWRCTRL_MEM_MAX);
  
  // Renable UART0 pins
  am_hal_gpio_pinconfig(48, g_AM_BSP_GPIO_COM_UART_TX);
  am_hal_gpio_pinconfig(49, g_AM_BSP_GPIO_COM_UART_RX);

  am_hal_pwrctrl_periph_enable(AM_HAL_PWRCTRL_PERIPH_UART0);

  initializeADC();

#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Waking up! Hello world!");
#endif
  deepSleepTimer = millis() ;
  sleep_mode_status = false;
}
```

Also, if DEBUG is defined, it'll crash after printing "going to sleep...", which I believe is being caused by a call to the UART after it's already been disabled for sleep. Unfortunately, that also makes it hard for me to see what's going on after the interrupt is triggered since I don't have my debug prints to tell me that. I did some reading around and while I did (and still might) suspect EMI causing these false-positives, this is all being powered by a 3.7V lipo battery and I couldn't see visible oscillations on my oscilloscope with the smallest interval of time available on it, nor was there enough of a peak and valley on the voltage to be visible that I could see either.

Does anyone have any clue what might be happening?

update: I added an extra line that would turn an LED on or off based on whether it was asleep (LED off) or awake (LED on) and also ran them in reverse for good measure (asleep LED on, awake LED off). The only time I saw the LED turn on was when it was asleep, and it was only for about half a second before it turned off again. So, it seems the interrupt is only being triggered the one time since it doesn't seem to go to sleep and then wake up (wash, rinse, repeat).

update 2: Ran another test with the oscilloscope to recheck for voltage variance. Oscilloscope was set to 500mV and 5 nanoseconds per division, and it was basically just a straight line all the way through, even when the interrupt triggered. No button press, no debounce, nothing.

update 3: thanks to jms' suggestions, I've found that once all the sleep-mode-specific code is removed from the interrupt and I'm just toggling some LEDs on and off, the button operation works fine. No debounce that I've observed, but I'm still seeing that same problem of the interrupt firing once as soon as it's attached to the pin, as evidenced by the following serial output.

*About to attach interrupt. button status: 1
Going to sleep...
Interrupt attached*

After that, I can press the button all I want and only get one response per button press.

I'm looking into seeing if manually clearing the interrupt flag before attaching it (per jms' suggestion) will fix it.

Comment: without attempting to analyze anything, what does your code do if you get switch bounce and so multiple edges? Your Rs and C around the switch appear to be an attempt at debounce, which may not work well enough.

Comment: @Neil_UK at the moment, debouce seems irrelevant since I don't even have to touch the button to get this to happen. As soon as I hit the line that attaches the interrupt to the pin I want to trigger it, the interrupt runs and then the whole thing seems to just shut down. No calling it again, no exiting it and waking up, nothing. There's no initial edge, just a permanent high signal

Comment: Comment out that sleep stuff and just get the interrupt alone working as expected, and only then include those sleep and wake up procedures. My first guess would be that the interrupt flag is set, and has to be cleared manually before attaching the interrupt.

Comment: I would also be careful about calling library functions within an interrupt - you can sometimes get unforeseen side effects. For example, if the arduino serial library sets up an ISR for servicing the serial interface and writing characters from a buffer to a HW register, what happens if that interrupt has a lower interrupt priority than sleepModeSwitch()? You might mess up the string being transmitted, or worse, some state machine in the code, when you call Serial.println(). It's probably OK, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @jms I'll update my question as I try your suggestions. In the meantime, would methods for clearing the interrupt flag differ between an in-house Arduino board (like the Uno or Nano) differ from a third-party board like the Artemis?

Comment: @jms, I will note that the serial.println is only there for debugging purposes and is not intended for any use beyond that. So far I'm only using it to spit out debug statements to help me track what's happening where and when.

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, but you should move C8 to be parallel with R3. Since this line has inverted logic, the default (uncharged) state of the capacitor should be that of the unasserted line, that is, 0V across the cap when 3.3V is on the line.

Comment: Also, if this is Eagle, your `SLEEP_INTERRUPT` should have a `!` in the name to indicate that this is active-low.

Comment: @Reinderien thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind